# Problem with importing external Single-File Components (via Vue CLI)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-sfc

I'm learning Vue and try to build first app with vue-cli.
I have simple local components that works well.
But I have a problem when I want to use external components.
E.g. 'vuetable-2'.
I install it locally via npm using terminal:

```
npm install --save vue-multiselect
```

Installation is succesfull and the 'vue-multiselect' folder appears in the 'node_modules' catalogue. Then I add proper references in my Single-File Component 'ms.vue' file:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Hello world!
        <label class="typo__label">Select with search</label>
        <multiselect v-model="value" :options="options" :custom-label="nameWithLang" placeholder="Select one" label="name" track-by="name"> 
        </multiselect>
        <pre class="language-json"><code>{{ value  }}</code></pre>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
    export default {
        components: {
            Multiselect
        },
        data () {
            return {
                value: { name: 'Vue.js', language: 'JavaScript' },
                options: [
                    { name: 'Vue.js', language: 'JavaScript' },
                    { name: 'Rails', language: 'Ruby' },
                    { name: 'Sinatra', language: 'Ruby' },
                    { name: 'Laravel', language: 'PHP' },
                    { name: 'Phoenix', language: 'Elixir' }
                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            nameWithLang ({ name, language }) {
                return `${name} — [${language}]`
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Everything compiles well, but when I go to the browser then the page is empty and got the following error in console:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5435 Uncaught TypeError: selfHook.call is not a function  
  at callSyncHook (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5435)  
    at applyOptions (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5227)  
    at finishComponentSetup (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6006)  
    at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5942)  
    at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5882)  
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4161)  
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4137)  
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3784)  
    at mountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3950)  
    at mountElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3896)
```

I've tried with other component and got same error.

My 'App.vue' file:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
        <ms></ms>                                         
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ms from './components/ms.vue'
    export default {
        name: 'App',
        components: {
            ms
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**edit 2020-09-02:**
What I see is that the issue appears only in Vue3. When I recreate the whole project in Vue2 everything works well. But still no idea about the core reason of the problem...